# How to find driver and port number from Windows Server for Progress database 11

Tags: windows, progress-db

I'm getting an error from report:

```
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "linkname" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
```

I'm checking to find out the installed driver and port number from the Windows server 2008 R2. I checked in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc" services file, but unable to get which exact service I need to check?

My ODBC data source administrator window is listing below drivers:

```
1. MySQL ODBC driver
2. Oracle in OraClient 10g
3. SQL Server
4. SQL Server native client
```

How can I find the detailed information; what is the current driver installed on what port number ? Is the current driver installed is compatible with Progress DB ? If it's not compatible, which latest driver I need to install to make it compatible with Progress 11?

Comment: Drivers are not "installed on [a] port number", they are only client-side **drivers** to connect to a database. None of the drivers listed is for Progress. You need to find and install the Progress driver, asking where to download it is off topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the SQL Client Access software from Progress web site.

https://www.progress.com/support/evaluation/download-resources/download-center

Look for the SQL Client Access:

[image: Screenshot from download page]